# How can I use order by at the same time with group by in SQL

Tags: sql

How can I use group by and also order by at the same time I want the drafter year to be ordered.

```
SELECT POSITION ,count(DRAFT_YEAR) "DRAFTED Players" 
FROM PLAYERS 
GROUP by POSITION or
order by Draft_year;
```

Comment: Can you give an example input and what you expect the output could be, as it stands it is a bit unclear of what you exactly want as draft_year is not even in the results, just the count of it.  Gordon's examples would give you a good clue as to how to do it however.

Comment: `I want the drafter year to be ordered` doesn't make sense for the presented query. Please try to make yourself clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can't as you have written it.  The column is not available in the aggregated data.

But you can use an *aggregation* function in the `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT POSITION, count(DRAFT_YEAR) as DRAFTED_Players
FROM PLAYERS
GROUP BY POSITION 
ORDER BY MAX(Draft_year);
```

Or a column alias:

```
SELECT POSITION, count(DRAFT_YEAR) as DRAFTED_Players
FROM PLAYERS
GROUP BY POSITION 
ORDER BY DRAFTED_Players DESC;
```